# Prevent closing browser tab/window in Angular 5.x

Tags: angular

How can we prevent closing a browser tab or the browser window itself in Angular 5.x?

I tried the solution recommended in another post ([Prevent closing browser tab when form is dirty in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719711/prevent-closing-browser-tab-when-form-is-dirty-in-angular-2)). Unfortunately, it's not working in Angular 5.x.

The solution below is partially working:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
handleClose(event) {
    event.returnValue = false;
```

What the above code does is that it displays a pop-up asking 'Do you want to leave this site?' with two buttons - Leave, Stay.

I tried the 'unload' and 'close' events instead of the 'beforeunload' also.

Advance thanks!

Comment: Referencing http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#unloading-documents, I don't think it is possible to completely prevent the user from closing the document. You can only prompt a confirmation window and let the user agent decide wether to close the window. This makes sense, since it would carry a huge potential for user exploitation, if you were able to stop the user from closing a window.

Comment: Yes. I guess this may lead to some issues. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe there's an Angular 5 problem or change I'm not aware of, but you're missing the '$' sign in the function that handles the event. Should be like this:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
handleClose($event) {
    $event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Edit: I can't comment, so that's why I've written this as a answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, unfortunately, it's not working. The '$' is optional.

Comment: Works like a charm. As a side note - setting `event.returnValue` to anything causes the popup window to appear. If you want to close normally simply leave it untouched.

Comment: Working like expected!

Answer (score 4):

> It is possible using both **RouteGuard** and pure **Javascript** code.

**Component:**

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
  ClientName: ['', [Validators.required]]
});

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event']) beforeUnloadHander(event: any) {
     // alert();
     debugger
     var isFormDirty = document.getElementById('profileformStatus').innerText;
     console.log(isFormDirty);
     if(isFormDirty == 'true'){
       return false;
     }
     else{
       return true;
     }
   }
```

**Component HTML:**

```
<div id="profileformStatus">{{profileForm.dirty ? true:false}}</div>
```

**Your Component Guard Service File(Optional):**

```
import { CanDeactivate } from "@angular/router";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { YourComponent } from "./projects/your-component";
@Injectable()

export class YourComponentCanDeactivateGuardService
    implements CanDeactivate<YourComponent> {

    canDeactivate(component: YourComponent): boolean {
        if (component.profileForm.dirty) {
            return confirm('Are you sure you want to discard your changes?');
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Your Module: add The Above Guard(Optional)**

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [YourComponentCanDeactivateGuardService]
})
```

Finally

**Update your routing module(Optional):**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        component: YourComponent,
        canDeactivate: [YourComponentCanDeactivateGuardService]
    }
];
```

Done. Now it will prevent reload/back navigation both.