# Detect event of closing browser angular 12

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I have to detect closing browser event so I close the user's connection.
I have tried the following method:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  beforeUnloadHandler(event) {
    /**
     * Post a single object to the server
     * Send Beacon API to keep request after browser windowunload event
     */
    navigator.sendBeacon(`${this.appConfigService.appConfig.apiUrl}/Account/LogoutDirectly/`);
  }
```

on my app.component.ts.
I tried this on both Chrome and Firefox. But it doesn't trigger anything.

Ressources where following:

[Angular 8 HostListener 'window:unload' how to make API call before unload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58903173/angular-8-hostlistener-windowunload-how-to-make-api-call-before-unload)

[Prevent closing browser tab/window in Angular 5.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48886460/prevent-closing-browser-tab-window-in-angular-5-x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
I have changed my code to following:

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload')
  async ngOnDestroy() {
    
    const userId = this.authenticationService.user?.profile?.sub; // get user id
    await this.userService.closeConnection(userId).toPromise(); // sign out user
    
  }
```

implementing ngOnDestroy and using async method directly to signout the user.

**Solution 2:**
You can also use the following code to detect when a tab is hidden and trigger your code:

```
@HostListener('document:visibilitychange', ['$event'])
  visibilitychange() {
    this.checkHiddenDocument().then(() => {});
  }

  async checkHiddenDocument() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
      const userId = this.authenticationService.user?.profile?.sub; // get user id
      if (!this.authenticationService.isRememberLogin() && userId) {
        await this.userService.closeConnections(userId).toPromise();
      }
    } else {
      // add logic
    }
  }
```

This solution is recommended by Mozilla developpers, as you can see in the following article: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon